# why doesnt event.preventDefault() work on html elements that are loaded in with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

This is my HTML form:

```html
<form class="access_form" action="/elements/login.php" method="POST">
  <div class="logo">
    <img src="/img/brand/logo.png" alt="logo" class="brand">
  </div>
  <div class="form">
    <div class="input_container">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Username" name="username" required>
      <input type="password" placeholder="Password" name="password" required>
      <button type="submit" name="login" id="submit">Login</button>
      <p id="alert"></p>
      <h5 class="linked_text_forgot"><a class="linked_text_forgot" href="javascript:">Forgot your password?</a></h5>
    </div>
    <div class="small_container">
      <h5 class="linked_text_signup">Click here to <a class="linked_text_signup" href="" onclick="return switch_form('sign_up');">Sign up</a></h5>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

This is my javascript:

```js
// form switching function to login or signup form
function switch_form(type) {
  if (type == "login") {
    $( 'form.access_form' ).replaceWith(login);
  } else if (type == "sign_up") {
    $( 'form.access_form' ).replaceWith(sign_up);
  }
  return false;
}

$( document ).ready(function() {
  $(".access_form").submit(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
  });
});

// sign up form
var sign_up = '<form class="access_form" action="/elements/signup.php" method="POST">' +
                '<div class="logo">' +
                  '<img src="/img/brand/logo.png" alt="logo" class="brand">' +
                '</div>' +
                '<div class="form">' +
                  '<div class="input_container">' +
                    '<input type="text" placeholder="Full name" name="fullname">' +
                    '<input type="text" placeholder="Email" name="email" id="user_email">' +
                    '<input type="text" placeholder="Username" name="username" id="user_uid">' +
                    '<input type="password" placeholder="Password" name="password" id="user_pswd">' +
                    '<button type="submit" name="sign_up" id="submit">Sign Up</button>' +
                    '<p class="alert"></p>' +
                  '</div>' +
                  '<div class="small_container">' +
                      '<h5 class="linked_text_signup">Click here to <a class="linked_text_signup" href="" onclick="return switch_form("login");">Login</a></h5>' +
                  '</div>' +
                '</div>' +
              '</form>';

// login form
var login =   '<form class="access_form" action="/elements/login.php" method="POST" id="login">' +
                '<div class="logo">' +
                  '<img src="/img/brand/logo.png" alt="logo" class="brand">' +
                '</div>' +
                '<div class="form">' +
                  '<div class="input_container">' +
                    '<input type="text" placeholder="Username" name="username" required>' +
                    '<input type="password" placeholder="Password" name="password" required>' +
                    '<button type="submit" name="login">Login</button>' +
                    '<p class="alert"></p>' +
                    '<h5 class="linked_text_forgot"><a class="linked_text_forgot" href="javascript:">Forgot your password?</a></h5>' +
                  '</div>' +
                  '<div class="small_container">' +
                      '<h5 class="linked_text_signup">Click here to <a class="linked_text_signup" href="" onclick="return switch_form("sign_up");">Sign up</a></h5>' +
                  '</div>' +
                '</div>' +
              '</form>';
```

So from my previous question i've found out that preventdefault works on the normally loaded html elements when the page starts however if you look at the javascript im loading in a signup form without reloading the page using jquery. I think that's why the preventdefault is not working on the html elements that are loaded on the page.

any suggestions for how i could go about this?

Comment: Typo here `$("access_form").submit(function(event){`. It has to be `$(".access_form").submit(function(event){`  . You are missing the dot. It has to be class selector

Comment: hey thanks for your answer ive just tried adding the "." in front and it still isnt carrying out prevent default

Comment: its in an external file

Comment: its included in the header tags on the top of the index page

Comment: if `$(".access_form").length` is zero, then that's your problem. You can't attach events to something that doesn't exist.

Comment: ive been trying all day so you think document ready will make it work? ive put changes in code above

Comment: Please refer to the linked duplicate post as to why this is not working and the different approaches you can take to resolve it.  One of which, is a document ready.

Comment: ive changed the question a bit because ive sort of figured out why it didnt work but dont know how i could fix this problem

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Basically Jquery attaches event handlers to elements only once, when the page is first loaded. Any elements that are created dynamically (don't exist when the page first loads), will need to have the event handlers manually added to them or you can attach the event handler to an element higher in the DOM that existed from page load. In your example you can attach the event handler to the document, which exists the entire time, and tell it to look for submit events from `.access_form` elements.

The answer on this page explains it a little better. 
[Click event doesn't work on dynamically generated elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6658752/click-event-doesnt-work-on-dynamically-generated-elements?noredirect=1&lq=1)

```
$( document ).on('submit','.access_form', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: Thanks so much man it worked!!! so how does this work then

Comment: ah that makes so much more sense now